# File reader / adding patterns from file Game of Life

Tags: java, parsing, conways-game-of-life

I am quite new to Java and I have this school assignment to write Conway's Game of Life. The task I am struggling with is reading a patterns from file. So far I got this code from tutorial from my school:

```
@FXML
private void readFromFile(){

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File openFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(openFile == null){
        return;
    }

    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(openFile.toPath())){
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            addMessage(line);
        }
    }catch (IOException ex){
        showIOErrorAlert(ex);
    }

}

@FXML
private void showIOErrorAlert(IOException ex){
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setContentText("IOException, filen cannot be open: " + ex);
    alert.show();
}
```

The code opens a window where I can choose a file from disk (I've downloaded all patterns in rle format , and I wish to open them rle format, because that is the assignments requirement). But when I choose a file nothing happens, not an error, nothing. What do I need to do that this work? Do I need to write a parser here? To read a rle format. I am using mvc model and java fxml this is my Cell class:

```
public class Cell extends Rectangle{

    public static final int CELL_SIZE = 5;

    private boolean alive;

    public Cell(){

        super(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
        setAlive(false);

    }

    public void setAlive(boolean bool){
        alive = bool;

        if (alive){
            setFill(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            setFill(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    public boolean isAlive(){

        return alive;
    }
}

Board class:

public class Board {

    public static final int COLUMNS = 90;
    public static final int ROWS = 210;

    private Cell[][] generation;

    public Board(){
        generation = new Cell[COLUMNS][ROWS];

        for(int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++){
                generation[x][y] = new Cell();
            }
        }
    }

    public Cell[][] getBoard(){

        return generation;
    }

    public void fill(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++){
                generation[x][y].setAlive(rand.nextBoolean());
            }
        }
    }

    public void reset(){
        for(int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++){
                generation[x][y].setAlive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public int countNeighbors(int x, int y){

        int neighbors = 0;

        //iteration starts with -1 in order to 'wrap' the grid around
        for (int a = -1; a < 2; a++){
            for (int b = -1; b < 2; b++){
                int nx = x + a;
                int ny = y + b;
                if (nx < 0){
                    nx = COLUMNS - 1;
                }
                if (ny < 0){
                    ny = ROWS - 1;
                }
                if (nx > COLUMNS - 1){
                    nx = 0;
                }
                if (ny > ROWS - 1){
                    ny = 0;
                }
                if(generation[nx][ny].isAlive()){
                    neighbors += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if(generation[x][y].isAlive())
            neighbors--;

        return neighbors;
    }

    public void renew(){
        Cell[][] nextGeneration = new Cell[COLUMNS][ROWS];

        for(int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++){
                nextGeneration[x][y] = new Cell();
                nextGeneration[x][y].setAlive(generation[x][y].isAlive());
            }
        }

        int neighborsCount = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++){
                neighborsCount = countNeighbors(x, y);

                if(generation[x][y].isAlive()){
                    if(neighborsCount < 2 || neighborsCount > 3)
                        nextGeneration[x][y].setAlive(false);
                }
                else{
                    if(neighborsCount == 3)
                        nextGeneration[x][y].setAlive(true);
                }
            }
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++){
                generation[x][y].setAlive(nextGeneration[x][y].isAlive());
            }
        }
    }
```

How to write a method that reads a rle format file and adds a pattern to my board?

Comment: You should either add alerts along the code or debug it... i.e. add an alert after the file was chosen, printing to the screen the openFile. Good luck

Comment: I wrote an RLE parser for C++, which I've [linked here](https://pastebin.com/JKRVRes0). I'll try to come up with a "Java Equivalent code" for it. The function which gets externally called by the rest of the program is `get_rle_encoded_points`, which is at the bottom of the paste, the rest are helper functions to make the code easier to reason about.